# Can you cast Animate Dead on someone under effect of Feign Death?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, targeting

The [*Feign Death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feign-death) spell (PHB, p. 240) says:

> For the spell’s duration, or until you use an action to touch the target and dismiss the spell, the target appears dead to all outward inspection and to spells used to determine the target’s status.

The [*Animate Dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) spell, on the other hand, says:

> This spell creates an undead servant. Choose a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small humanoid within range. Your spell imbues the target with a foul mimicry of life, raising it as an undead creature. The target becomes a skeleton if you chose bones or a zombie if you chose a corpse (the DM has the creature's game statistics).

*Feign Death* has this strange clause that all spells used to detect the target status register it as being dead. *Animate Dead* takes a corpse of a dead creature and create a zombie out of it.

On one hand, a *Feigned* creature isn't a corpse, so it isn't a valid target for *Animate Dead*. On the other hand, if *Animate Dead* fails, then the creature isn't a corpse, but that would violate the clause from *Feign Death* that says the target appears dead to spells used to determine the target status and now my head is hurting and I don't understand anything anymore.

What happens if you cast *Animate Dead* on a creature currently under effect of *Feign Death* to determine if it is dead?

Would you end up with some weird living zombie that is undead but not really?

Comment: Related: [Can the Nystul's Magic Aura spell make you immune/unable to be targeted by the Dominate Person spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67545/48827)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### *Animate dead* wouldn't work; the creature's actual type is unchanged.

The *animate dead* spell must be cast on "a pile of bones or a corpse of a Medium or Small humanoid within range", as you quoted - but the *feign death* spell doesn't turn a creature into a corpse (or a pile of bones).

*Feign death* says "the target appears dead to all outward inspection and to spells used to determine the target’s status." However, the *animate dead* spell is not a spell used to determine the target's status; it is simply a spell that only works on dead creatures. In other words, it is a **prerequisite**/**requirement** of the spell - not a **function** of the spell.

Because *feign death* doesn't change the actual status of the target, the target of *feign death* is not a valid target for the *animate dead* spell. One way to handle this situation is using the optional rule on [invalid spell targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#InvalidSpellTargets) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (p. 85):

> If you cast a spell on someone or something that can’t be affected by the spell, nothing happens to that target, but if you used a spell slot to cast the spell, the slot is still expended. If the spell normally has no effect on a target that succeeds on a saving throw, the invalid target appears to have succeeded on its saving throw, even though it didn’t attempt one (giving no hint that the creature is in fact an invalid target). Otherwise, you perceive that the spell did nothing to the target.

Following this rule, nothing would happen to the target after *animate dead* was cast; the spell slot would be expended, but *animate dead* would fail. However, no indication is given as to why the spell failed; as Miniman pointed out in a comment on this answer, another reason it could fail is that it's under the effect of a *gentle repose* spell, for example.

Comment: Given that it seems to be a concern for the OP, it's worth noting that the failure of *animate dead* doesn't actually prove the the target isn't a corpse - it could be under the effect of a *gentle repose* spell, for example.

Comment: @Miniman: I considered mentioning that it'd give no indication of the reason for failure but wasn't sure it'd matter - thanks for the example of when it would!

Comment: Another way for the spell to inexplicably fail would be if you cast it on the corpse of a zombie or skeleton, or just a non-undead non-humanoid corpse with vaguely humanoid anatomy.

Comment: Corpses are technically objects as well... but I suppose that that would open up a bunch of metagame questions on how to test, that have already answered.

Comment: If you're casting _animate dead_ specifically to find out if the target is dead, then it _is_ a spell used to determine the target's status, yeah?

Comment: @MarkWells: *Animate dead*'s purpose is not to determine the target's status, no matter what reason you announce to the universe first. :P

Comment: @V2Blast That's an interesting discussion. What does the _intent_ of the character has to do with the purpose of the spell? Is an out-of-the-box use of a spell enough to make it a "spell used for X or Y"? So many implications!

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity for the target to make a Bluff roll to "rise from their grave" if they know what spell is being cast...

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of *Feign Death*'s effect would be that "spells used to determine the target's status" give you said status information as an explicit part of their effect, such as *Detect Thoughts* or Plane of Life's *[Detect Lifeforce](https://dnd-wiki.org/wiki/Detect_Lifeforce_(3.5e_Spell))*. The only information you explicitly gain from casting *Animate Dead* on a feigning target is "my spell failed", not "the target is invalid because it's alive". "The target is actually alive" is an inference you make, which I'd argue is a perfectly valid way to work around *Feign Death*.

Comment: Detect Lifeforce is a 3.5 spell. I think it would be better to use a 5e spell like [Detect Evil and Good](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-evil-and-good) as an example :)

Comment: Fair point, but I skipped DEaG in favor of Detect Lifeforce for two reasons: a reasonably significant number of enemies wouldn't fall under the detectable creature types of "aberration, celestial, elemental, fey, fiend, or undead", and I didn't do my homework on the differences between 3.5e and 5e Feign Death. :P

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.