# Is "targets a willing creature" a spell requirement ignored by the Wish spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

I want to abuse the *Wish* spell by casting *Nystul's magic aura* on enemies to make them count as plants for spell effects and then use *Blight* for instakills.

Is "targets a willing creature" a spell requirement ignored by the Wish spell?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. I've closed this as a duplicate, we have something of a canonical question for what counts as a requirement that can be ignored with *wish*, I think that should answer your specific question here.

Comment: Maximising 8d8 with a 9th level spell is not a great use of wish

Comment: I'll also note that the *Mask* effect of *Nystul's Magic Aura* would not change how *Blight* works anyway; *Blight* is not a spell that detects creature types, and *Mask* specifically applies to "spells and magical effects that detect creature types". [It doesn't actually make them a plant for any other purpose](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67545/28941), so they won't take extra damage.