# Can Magic Aura fool Hallow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Let's say I'm a PC who would be excluded by a [hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow) effect, but I don't want my party members to know. I've been casting [Magic Aura](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura) to hide the fact that I'm undead from the paladin.

Our cleric has decided to hallow a small shrine, and asked the rest of the party to rest in the safe space. Does *magic aura*'s "mask" feature allow me to enter the *hallow*-ed area?

Similarly, could my friend the orc use *magic aura* to enter the area without having to make a save to be exempted from the other status effect (there are a lot of enemy orcs around, so the cleric wants orcs to get the "fear" effect)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### This works for masking undead.

*Magic aura* states:

> You change the way the target appears to spells and magical effects that detect creature types, such as a paladin’s Divine Sense or the trigger of a symbol spell.

This is a blanket coverage of magical effects that detect creature types, *hallow* is one such effect, and undead is a creature type. The Mask effect of *magic aura* fools *hallow* for an undead wanting to appear humanoid.

#### However, “orc” is not a creature type.

*Magic aura* will mask an undead as a humanoid, but it cannot make an orc appear as not an orc, since it only affects *creature type*, and an orc’s creature type is humanoid.

Comment: Is hallow a "spell" or "magical effect" that will "detect creature type?" I can't see how.

Comment: @MichaelW. It is a spell (thus a magical effect) that applies to certain creature types. How does it know what creatures to apply the effect to? It detects if the creature’s creature type is one of those listed.

Comment: @MichaelW., It doesn't report the detection, but it does detect undead. This is no different than symbol spells, which *Magic Aura* provides as an example.

Comment: @ikegami It's very different from symbol spells. Symbol spells have triggers. Hallow is always on. Hallow does not need to be triggered to activate. It's activated for the full duration. Hallow doesn't need to detect undead or an elemental to function, it's a constant effect. It's more like Protection From Evil than Symbol. Would you also argue that Protection From Evil can be tricked?

Comment: @Michael W., They both create continuous effect that do something when a creature of a specific type is present. Sure, what they do is different, but that's not relevant. And sure, *Magic Aura* is closer to *Protection from Evil* than *Symbol*, but not in any way that matters here.

Comment: @MichaelW. *Any spell or magical effect that has to detect your creature type in order to affect you can be fooled*. That’s the point of the feature.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Not true. See: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67545/can-the-nystuls-magic-aura-spell-make-you-immune-to-unable-to-be-targeted-by-th Magic Aura is aimed at Divination. Hallow isn't divination.

Comment: @MichaelW. I agree with the answer there but I don’t think it applies here. Sounds like you’re pretty sure what the answer here should be, so if you want to object to mine further do so in your own answer post.

Comment: @Michael W. Re "*Magic Aura is aimed at Divination.*",  If you mean magic of the Divination school, than that can't possibly be correct because *Symbol* isn't a divination spell. It's obviously poorly written, but it must be using some broader meaning for divination.

Comment: And before you claim that divining implies providing the divined information to the caster, note that *Symbol* does not do that either.